How best to to dynamically query S3 folders
We have an extremely large S3 bucket, which is divided into folders by date. e.g.

dt=2024-11-19
dt=2024-11-20
dt=2024-11-21

I run queries through Redshift, and was instructed to always filter by the dt field to keep costs down.
Now I'm trying to write a script that will dynamically query the last 2 days of data, and am wondering which method would be fastest/cheapest:

SELECT ... FROM src WHERE dt >= CAST(DATEADD (day,-1,GETDATE ()) AS DATE)


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE var AS (SELECT CAST(DATEADD (day,-1,GETDATE ()) AS DATE) AS yday);
SELECT ... FROM src WHERE dt >= (SELECT yday FROM var)


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE var AS (SELECT CAST(DATEADD (day,-1,GETDATE ()) AS DATE) AS yday);
SELECT ... FROM src JOIN var ON src.dt >= var.yday

Or is there a better way that I  haven't thought of yet?

When the table was created, did you use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ... PARTITIONED BY ...? That tells Redshift to selectively use the directories. If so, then your first query should work. Avoid creating a temporary table since that has to copy the data, which would be wasteful of resources. See: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE - Amazon Redshift

I didn't create the table, it's owned by another team; but after running some tests, it looks like you're correct about the first query.
